# Array enters each row twice

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops

I have a model that has a function to query the subjects a student is enrolled in.

```
public function getAllSubjects($username){
    $this->db->select('student.username, subjects.subject_name, teacher.firstname as TeachersFirstName, teacher.surname as TeacherSurname');
    $this->db->from('users student');
    $this->db->join('student_subjects', 'student.username = student_subjects.student_username', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('subjects', 'student_subjects.subject_id = subjects.subject_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('users teacher', 'subjects.teacher_username = teacher.username', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('student.username', $username);
    $studentSubjQuery = $this->db->get('users');
    return $studentSubjQuery->result_array();
}
```

In the controller, I call the function from the model and store the returned array into the data and passed it to the view. Now, when I try to print the array, the rows are stored twice in an array. Here is the printed array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => dirkjan021
            [subject_name] => Chemistry
            [TeachersFirstName] => Teacher 1
            [TeacherSurname] => Teacher 1 Surname
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => dirkjan021
            [subject_name] => Chemistry
            [TeachersFirstName] => Teacher 1
            [TeacherSurname] => Teacher 1 Surname
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [username] => dirkjan021
            [subject_name] => Physics
            [TeachersFirstName] => Teacher 1
            [TeacherSurname] => Teacher 1 Surname
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [username] => dirkjan021
            [subject_name] => Physics
            [TeachersFirstName] => Teacher 1
            [TeacherSurname] => Teacher 1 Surname
        )

)
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public function acads()
{
    if (!$this->session->userdata('username')) {
        // Redirect to homepage
        redirect('../');
    } else {
        // Allow Access to User's Acads
        $data['userInfo'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
        // Query User Subjects
        $this->load->model('usersubject_model');
        $data['userSubjects'] = $this->usersubject_model->getAllSubjects($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->load->view('view_userAcads', $data);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the query according to '$this->output->profiler(TRUE)':

```
SELECT `student`.`username`, `subjects`.`subject_name`, `teacher`.`firstname` as TeachersFirstName, `teacher`.`surname` as TeacherSurname
FROM (`users` student, `users`)
INNER JOIN `student_subjects` ON `student`.`username` = `student_subjects`.`student_username`
INNER JOIN `subjects` ON `student_subjects`.`subject_id` = `subjects`.`subject_id`
INNER JOIN `users` teacher ON `subjects`.`teacher_username` = `teacher`.`username`
WHERE `student`.`username` =  'dirkjan021'
```

Comment: Put `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in your acads() method and reload the page. Then can you copy and paste the query into the question as well?

Comment: Did you tried adding a group by condition?

Comment: @RossWilson I guess it's from the FROM line. It has 'users' student AND 'users'.

Comment: @Filo How do you do that? And how will it solve the issue?

Comment: @RossWilson Since the possible culprit may be the two tables called in the FROM line, how do I get to self-join my table. Originally, I used FROM (users student) to differentiate it to the teachers. How do I assign the $query = to the FROM ('users' student) using Codeigniter.

Comment: Hey man, sorry I didn't get back to you yesterday. I'm glad you found the solution! One thing I would suggest is either camelCasing or using underscores instead of whitespace because it helps avoid issues like this and it also follows coding standards :)

Answer (score 2):

I got it now. The model query originally "queries twice" FROM ('users' student, 'users') because I had these two lines:
`$this->db->from('users' student);`
`$this->db->get('users');`

What I did was I removed the db->from and edited `db->get` to `db->get('users' student);`